# Description of the $\sigma$-algebra of an outer measure.

Tags: measure-theory, real-numbers

Let $\mu : P(\Bbb{R}) \hookrightarrow [0,+ \infty]$ the outer measure such that $\mu(A)=0$ if $A$ is countable and $\mu(A)=1$ if $A$ is uncountable. It is required to describe the $\mu$-measurable sets, denoted by $\mathcal{M}_\mu$

I have noticed that maybe $\mathcal{M}_\mu=\{A\subset \Bbb{R}: A$ is countable or $A^c$ is countable$\}$ and I want to know if my prove is correct.

$\fbox{$\subset$}$ Let $A\in \mathcal{M}_\mu$ and $E\subset \Bbb{R}$ such that $E^c$ is countable.
Then, by the definition of $\mu$ we have:
$$1=\mu(E)=\mu(E\cap A) + \mu(E\cap A^c)$$
It follows that $E\cap A$ is countable or $E\cap A^c$ is countable. If $E\cap A$ is countable (the other case is similar), $A$ is also countable since $A=(E\cap A) \cup (E^c\cap A)$ which is the union of two countable sets.

$\fbox{$\supset$}$ Let $A\subset \Bbb{R}$ such that $A$ is countable or $A^c$ is countable and $E\subset \Bbb{R}$.

- If $E$ is countable then $\mu(E)=0=\mu(E\cap A)+\mu(E\cap A^c)$
- If $E$ is uncountable and $A^c$ is countable, then $E\cap A = E \setminus (E\cap A^c)$ is uncountable since the difference between an uncountable and a countable set is uncountable. Then: $\mu(E)=1=1+0=\mu(E\cap A) + \mu(E\cap A^c)$ (notice that the case in which $A$ is countable is similar).

Comment: yes , it's fine

Comment: @MahmoudMrowi thanks!